# wide multiplication support in c

Tags: c, algorithm, x86, int, integer-arithmetic

There is some confussion for me if c supports wide multiplication
i mean something like this

```
int_32 a = 1000*1000*1000;
int_32 b = 1000*1000*1000;
int_64 c = a*b;
```

or for smaller types too

some say that c do not support this? (and it will cut the result,
as i understand to a lower 32 bit part of it then copy this to int_64,
some say even if b is int_64 it will do the same i mean it will cut
the result to 32) - but im not sure if its true as it seem bad

what with smaller types?

could someone explain this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As both `a` and `b` are 32-bit integers, the multiplication will be done using 32-bit integers, and it will overflow before being assigned to the 64-bit `c` variable.

If, on the other hand, at least one of `a` or `b` was also a 64-bit integer, then the non-64-bit integer will be converted to a 64 bit integer and the whole multiplication will be done using 64-bit values.

---

For arithmetic expression, such as addition, value of types smaller than `int` will be *promoted* to `int`. If the expression involves a type *larger* than `int` then all values will be promoted to the largest type. And the whole expression will be performed using the largest type.

So if you have a variable of type `short` (which on modern 32 and 64 bit platforms is 16 bits) is in an expression together with a `long long` (64 bits currently), then the `short` variable will be promoted to `long long`, and the expression evaluated.

---

Back to your code, if you have

```
int32_t a = ...;  // 32 bit integer
int64_t b = ...;  // 64 bit integer
int64_t c = a * b;
```

The compiler will do the equivalent of

```
int64_t temp_a = a;  // Promote `a` to a 64 bit integer
c = temp_a * b;
```

Comment: +1 but the type of the variable does not change; only the type of the value.

Comment: In C such overflow (for signed integers) is actually undefined behaviour, another possibility to solve this is to simply cast at least one operand (no matter which one) e.g. `int64_t c = (int64_t) a * b;`

Comment: so im my oryginal example is it undefined or it will be cutted to down 32 bits of proper 64 bit results or yet something other?

Comment: @user2214913 Because signed integer overflow is undefined, you will probably not get the result you expect. The program will not crash though.

Comment: @user2214913: C99/C11 `§3.4.3/3`: "An example of undefined behavior is the behavior on integer overflow.". GCC has `-fno-strict-overflow` and `-fwrapv` switches to allow signed overflow using two's complement (i.e. despite the fact that it's UB according to standard), but I wouldn't recommend it in real code.

Comment: @gs you mean it will be proper calculated then low part of result will be stored? yet one question - assembly seem to support such wide multiplies but is it supporitin it for moth singed and unsigned versions?

Comment: @user2214913: Undefined behaviour simply means that anything could happen and you can't count on it in any case. Assembly is different story, this surely depends on particular ISA. Note that GCC supports [inline assembly](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Using-Assembly-Language-with-C.html#Using-Assembly-Language-with-C), so theoretically you can use specific in-place instructions (but it' really outside of scope of C language itself).

Answer (score 0):

Int in 32 bit is 2 bytes and in 64 bits is 4 bytes. Long int in both is 4 bytes.

Comment: No int is 8 byte whether 32 or 64, short or long.

Comment: Wrong. On most 64-bit Unix-like OSes long int is 8 bytes